# How to find an entire function $f(z)$ such that $f(n) = \sqrt {|n|}$ for every integer $n$?

Tags: complex-analysis, entire-functions

How to find an entire function $f(z)$ such that $f(n) = \sqrt {|n|}$ for every integer $n$?

Now my thinking is to create a series $\displaystyle\sum_{k=-\infty}^\infty f_{k}(z)$ such that $f_{k}(z)=\sqrt{|k|}$ and the series is convergent for every $z$.

Thanks for any help

Comment: I thought of $$f(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}\sqrt{|n|}  \frac{\sin2\pi x}{x-n}$$ because for any interger $m$ $$f(z)=\sum_{n=-m}^{m}\sqrt{|n|}  \frac{\sin2\pi x}{x-n}$$ is entire and has the values you want on all the integers between $-m$ and $m$.  Unfortunately the infinite series has some _serious_ convergence issues, and doesn't work at all.

Answer (score 2):

the existence of such thing is standard, see Rudin under 'interpolation'.  To actually construct it , you are multiplying by $\sum  \sqrt{\vert n \vert} \frac 1 {x-n}$ which has the correct poles at n but doesn't converge. Try $\sum  \sqrt{\vert n \vert} (\frac 1 {x-n} - \frac 1 n)$ which has the same poles & residues but speeds up the convergence